# is there an alternative to using mod "%" in python

Tags: python, math, time, modulo

I am trying to cycle through a list of numbers (mostly decimals), but I want to return both 0.0 and the max number.
for example

```
maxNum = 3.0 
steps = 5
increment = 0
time = 10
while increment < time:
    print increment * (maxNum / steps)% maxNum
    increment+=1
```

#

I am getting this as an output

```
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.8
2.4
0.0
```

but I want 3.0 as the largest number and to start back at 0.0 I.E.

```
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.8
2.4
3.0
0.0
```

Note, I have to avoid logical loops for the calculation part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only small change did the trick:

```
maxNum = 3.0
steps = 5
i = 0
times = 10
step = maxNum / steps
while (i < times):
    print(step * (i % (steps + 1)))
    i += 1

0.0
0.6
1.2
1.7999999999999998
2.4
3.0
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.7999999999999998
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the numbers that you want then use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle through them:

```
import itertools
nums  = itertools.cycle(0.6*i for i in range(6))
for t in range(10):
    print(next(nums))
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.7999999999999998
2.4
3.0
0.0
0.6
1.2
1.7999999999999998
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `if` statement that looks ahead if the next printed number is `0.0` then print the `maxNum`

```
maxNum = 3.0
steps = 5
increment = 0
time = 10

while increment < time:
    print(round(increment * (maxNum / steps)% maxNum, 2))
    increment+=1
    if (round(increment * (maxNum / steps)% maxNum, 2)) == 0.0:
        print(maxNum)
```

> ```
> 0.0
> 0.6
> 1.2
> 1.8
> 2.4
> 3.0
> 0.0
> 0.6
> 1.2
> 1.8
> 2.4
> 3.0
> ```